# PyGitHub .RateLimitExceededException: 403 Authentication Trouble

Tags: python, authentication, github, pygithub

I have been attempting to use PyGitHub to edit/update my repository files using PyGitHub, however (I guess I tried to access it too many times :P) it gives me this error:

```
github.GithubException.RateLimitExceededException: 403 {"message": "API rate limit exceeded for xx.xx.xx.xxxx. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#rate-limiting"}
```

I was accessing the data just fine before. I had researched it and in the effort to fix the problem I had replaced my username with an access token. Here is my full code:

```
from github import Github


# Github username
username = "JosephCWatkins"
password = yeoldepasswordhere
# pygithub object
g = Github(yeolaccesstokenhere, password) 
user = g.get_user(username)


repof =  g.get_repo("JosephCWatkins/moonspellprojectprogress") 


#me trying to access the data :P: 
contents = repof.get_contents("test.txt")
print(contents.content.split.__doc__())
```

It says that I must authenticate myself which would give me a higher rate limit, but the best I could figure out on trying to solve it was adding the access token. Am I doing something wrong? How can I authenticate myself so I can continue working with the API? And also, if you could help me be able to print the contents of a repository file. Thank You. :)

Answer (score 0):

The first part of my question is still unanswered, but I accessed the contents of my GitHub Repository File with this code:

```
    repo =  g.get_repo("username/repositoryname") 
    contents = repo.get_contents("filename.filetype").decoded_content
```

I know it sounds simple but the documentation does not go into the various functions like it should, it mostly only gives examples. Plus the internet lacks a simple answer to this problem. For anyone who wants to access their GitHub file via PyGitHub, here it is.